# How can I associate bash command to Git Bash instead of WSL Bash?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, git-bash

I have Git Bash and WSL Bash installed. Currently bash command is associated to WSL Bash. Can I link it to Git bash instead?

Comment: You would have to change order of the paths within your PATH variable.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @Ramhound WSL Bash is located in the System32 folder, which is not included in PATH variable of my machine

Comment: I will repeat my suggestion since your last comment does not really answer the question I raised.  The path to GIT bash should be the first entry in the system variable, this will make it so Git bash is the first application found, instead of WSL bash.exe.

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, I tried. It doesn't work even if I put `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\` to the first row of PATH variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows: How to make cygwin bash.exe to take precedence over wsl in command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/1733124/windows-how-to-make-cygwin-bash-exe-to-take-precedence-over-wsl-in-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

There may be cleaner solutions, but I was able to get around this by doing either of the following:

1. Specify the absolute path to Git Bash's `bash` executable each time:

```
& "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe" -c "echo hello"
```

2. Create a Powershell alias for Git Bash's `bash` executable and use that:

```
New-Alias -Name git-bash -Value "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe"
git-bash -c "echo hello"
```